# $http Get logic to only allow 200 OK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build some logic into my api so it will exclude objects that have a a URL in the field "image" which returns a 4xx, 5xx, or times out over 4000ms.

The code below doesn't quite work- as it still allows 404 and blank images.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Also, here it is in a plunker- http://plnkr.co/edit/7ScnGyy2eAmGwcJ7XZ2Z?p=preview

Example of json: {id:242, image:"www.image.com/1.jpg",name:"blah blah"}

```
.controller('CardsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$q', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicModal', 'TDCardDelegate', 'cardsApi', '$http', '$timeout', '$element',
  function($scope, $http, $state, $q, $ionicLoading, $ionicModal, TDCardDelegate, cardsApi, $http, $timeout, $element) {


    var loginuid = window.localStorage.getItem('uid');
    console.log(loginuid);


    var MIN_CARDS = 7;

    console.log('CARDS CTRL');
    $scope.cards = [];

    cardsApi.getApiData()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.data); //Shows log of API incoming
        $scope.cards = result.data;

        result.data.forEach(function(card) {
          var imgurl = card.image;
          console.log(imgurl);
          var canceler = $q.defer();
          $http.get(imgurl, {
              timeout: canceler.promise
            })
            .then(function mySuccess(response) {
              console.log(response.status);

            }, function myError(response) {
              console.log(response.status);

              if (response.status == 404) {
                $scope.cards.splice(card, 1);
              }
              // console.log('deleted');
              var imgpid = "#card-image-" + card.vari;
              console.log(imgpid);
              $(imgpid).parent().remove();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {

            });
          $timeout(function() {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            canceler.resolve();
          }, 4000);
        });

      })
```

Comment: create an image loader directive that uses native image load and error callbacks. Won't run into CORS issues that you will using ajax

Comment: I am not encountering CORS issues ( I dont think). Could you illustrate with an example?

Comment: in directive ... `element.on('load', function(...` and `element.on('error', func...`

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line from :

```
<img class="storelogo-image" ng-src="{{card.store__logo}}">
```

to

```
   <img class="storelogo-image" ng-src="{{card.store__logo.indexOf('http://')> -1 ?card.store__logo :''}}">
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**[The plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xz2HWsIwStwl6jpRSMpA?p=preview)**

I added `ng-if="card.image"` to `<td-card ng-if="card.image" ng-repeat="card in cards"`...

This will prevent the template from generating and empty image template in the event that there is no image available

Comment: On a second thought, maybe have a boolean that indicates whether or not the image loaded and ng-if on that boolean per image.

Comment: Could you show me with an example with the Boolean? Your changes did not work (in the Plunker)

Comment: I updated [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xz2HWsIwStwl6jpRSMpA?p=preview). I added the boolean property to each card on 'getApiData()' with default value false. Then, on the success function of the promise I set it to true. On the html side by using ng-show on your ng-repeat the template will not be shown until the image has loaded. Whereas using ng-if the template is not rendered until the image has loaded. I think that answers your question about loading. Where and how to use the solution is a design choice.

Comment: I dont quite follow, and your Plunker example isn't working with it. Could you please check it?